# Laravel zipArchive throws Site can't be reached

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to download pdf files and zip it with ZipArchive. But it gives me 'This site can't be reached' error..

Here is my code:

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$archive_file_name = date('YmdHis') . '.zip';

if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, $zip::CREATE) !== true) {
    exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
}

foreach ($Contracts as $Contract) {

    if (!$Contract->parent_id) {
        $template = $request->template;
    } else {
        $template = $request->template_amendment;
    }

    $pdf = $Contract->getPdfPath($template);

    /** @var \Dompdf\Dompdf $dompdf */
    if (!$pdf && $dompdf = $Contract->generatePdf(true, true, $template)) $pdf = $dompdf->path;

    $ContractPdf = \App\Models\ContractPdf::where('contract_id', $Contract->id)->where('pdf_template', $template)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
    $unprotected = str_replace($ContractPdf->pdf_filename, 'unprotected/' . $ContractPdf->pdf_filename, $pdf);

    if ($unprotected && file_exists($unprotected)) $pdf = $unprotected;

    $zip->addFile($Storage->url($pdf), $ContractPdf->pdf_filename);

}

$zip->close();

//then send the headers to force download the zip file
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile("$archive_file_name");
exit;
```

is the problem in my code or in local settings? and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Case closed!

what stupid I am! I should've put `$pdf` in `addFile()` parameter instead of `$Storage->url($pdf)`